# Is it possible to create a node group in animation nodes?

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I have a big node tree that I would like to collapse into a single node with custom inputs  (in shading you can do that pressing ctrl-g), is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but it works differently than in the Shader Node tree. You don't have a "Sublayer" tree where you go and edit the node group's insides.

You first add a *Group Input* node by going *Add > Subprograms > Group*

Then you can add operations like in regular subprograms. Make sure you don't have circular dependencies and that all the group logic is contained within it. The nodes will take the color of the group by default.

[image]

To get ouput values, click on *Output Node* on the bottom of the *Group Input* node and link it as you wish.

[image]

You can Invoke the Group by going *Add > Subprograms > - My Group* (You can change the name in the Input node).

[image]

Comment: Okey... But I can't hide all the nodes of that group right? I mean, at the end I have that huge group in other part of the node tree. But that's okey... Could be nice to do it at the same way that in the Shader editor. Anyway, thank you!!

Comment: @Artichoke You can always create another Animation Nodes tree and put the group there. In my opinion it is more convenient that way than the layer of abstraction in the shader editor. I just wish it was easier to scroll through a high number of node trees.

Comment: Okey, I like that one, I didn't know that I could mix node trees . Thanks!